# How to get number of rows and columns from a matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, api, matplotlib, plot

I have a function that dynamically creates figures of different columns and rows:

```
import random

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def build_dynamic_plot():
    """Return a figure with random rows and columns."""
    nrows = random.randrange(1, 10)
    ncols = random.randrange(1, 10)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols)

    return fig.tight_layout()

plot = build_dynamic_plot()
```

[image: sample output]

Using the matplotlib API, how do I get the number of rows and columns from the figure, which are dynamically generated, e.g. `plot.get_rows` and `plot.get_cols`?  I ultimately need to verify that the row by column dimensions are accurate.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there no API for this, but you can get the grid size by:

```
fig.axes[0].get_subplotspec().get_gridspec().get_geometry()
```

Answer (score 4):

Although HYRY's answer was helpful and it might work sometimes (or worked before), the true solution should be:

```
fig.axes[0].get_subplotspec().get_topmost_subplotspec().get_gridspec().get_geometry()
```